# Stepwise fill dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using a for-loop to perform operations on specific subsets of my data. At the end of each iteration of the for loop, I have all the values that I need to fill a row of my dataframe.

So far I tried

```
df=NULL
for(...){  
//stuff to calculate   
newline=c(allthethingscalculated)  
df=rbind(df,newline)
}
```

this results in the contents of the dataframe not being accessable using '$' , because the rows are then atomic vectors.

I also tried to append the values I get at the end of each iteration to an already existing vector and when the for loop ends create a dataframe from these vectors using but appending the values to the respective vector didn't work, the values weren't added.

```
x<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,...)
```

Any ideas on this?

---

Since my for loop iterates over IDs in my data, I realized I could do something like this:

```
uids=unique(data$id)
filler=c(1:length(uids))
df=data.frame(uids,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler)

for(i in uids){
...
df[i,]<-newline
}
```

I used *filler* to create a dataframe with the correct number of columns and rows so I don't get an error like 'replacement has length of 9, replacement has length of 1'

Is there a better way to do this? Using this approach I still have the values of *filler* in the respective row that I'd need to remove?

Comment: is length of `newline` always same after every iteration?

Comment: If you know in advance the number of iterations, why not fill a data.frame with NAs and replace each row with your calculations? Something like `df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, i*ncols, ncol=ncols))`

Comment: maybe at the start you'll have to say:`df <- data.frame()`. In any case, there's no example and I find the question a bit unclear.

Comment: I updated my question with my progress, this should make it clearer

Comment: I believe you would be better served with a `lapply` or `sapply` loop, which combines the results for you. If you don't like those you could use a `foreach` (from package foreach) loop, which also offers a `.combine` parameter. Lastly, you can of course do this with a `for` loop, but we need a reproducible example to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, can your show us you data ?

```
R) x=data.frame(a=rep(1,3),b=rep(2,3),c=rep(3,3))
R) d=c(4,4,4)
R) rbind(x,d)
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 1 2 3
3 1 2 3
4 4 4 4
R) cbind(x,d)
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4
3 1 2 3 4
```